# Why does VLC force 360 videos to show only the center viewport?

Tags: vlc, libvlcsharp

I currently use the vlc for unity (libvlcsharp) for a media player project.

It performs well but when I play the 360 video it automatically shows the center viewport of the panorama video due to the metadata.

Why does the VLC do things like this? And according to the forum, I cannot disable this feature?

Comment: not yet supported by VLC/LibVLC